# TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null when trying to create a parargaph

Tags: reactjs

```js
    paragraph() {
        var p = document.createElement("P");
        p.innerHTML = "This is a paragraph";
        document.getElementById("builderSection").appendChild(p);
    }

  render() {
  return (
      <button onClick={this.paragraph()}>Paragraph</button>
      <div id="builderSection">

      </div>
  )
  }
```

I'm getting the error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` because paragraph is running before return or smth related, any idea how can i patch?

Comment: `onClick={this.paragraph()}` -> `onClick={this.paragraph}`, although its not best practice to append an element directly like this

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava The issue is resolved, but what would be the best way to append an element?

Comment: You can look for some answers here, one that can guide you is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30721978/7867822

Comment: You have to useState, create an array of paragraphs to be added and then render the paragraphs in the builderSection.

Answer (score 0):

To somewhat answer your question the way to create an arbitrary number of elements is to hold them in array.

In your case you need to use `useState` to hold that array and update it whenever the button is clicked, so:

```
const [paragraphs, setParagraphs] = useState([]);

const addParagraphOnClick = () => {
  setParagraphs(prevState => {
    return [...prevState, <p>New Paragraph</p>];
  });
};
```

And then to render:

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={addParagraphsOnClick}>Paragraph</button>
      {paragraphs.map(paragraph => { return paragraph })}
    </>
  )
}
```